# C++ Recursion to detect duplicates in row and column of grid

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm coding a recursive algorithm to take a user input N and make a N x N grid where the same number does not appear twice on either a row or a column. Almost everything's working, and duplicates don't appear in columns, but I'm having trouble getting rows working.

My code for checking duplicates in rows is the function noRowDuplicates. Duplicates are still appearing, and occasionally it'll throw a segmentation fault, but I'm not sure why.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
// Author: Eric Benjamin
// This problem was solved using recursion. fill() is the recursive function.


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void fillOptions();
void fill(int arrayPosition);
int inputNum;
int gridSize;
int *grid;
int allOptionsSize = 0;
int *allOptions;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter a number!" << endl;
    cin >> inputNum;
    gridSize = inputNum * inputNum;

    grid = new int[gridSize];
    allOptions = new int[inputNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNum; i++) {
         allOptions[i] = i + 1;
         allOptionsSize++;
    }

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    fill(0);

    delete[] grid;
    delete[] allOptions;
    return 0;
}

bool noColumnDuplicates(int arrPosition, int valueToCheck) {
    for (int i = 1; i < inputNum; i++) {
        if (arrPosition - (inputNum * i) >= 0) {
            if (grid[arrPosition - (inputNum * i)] == valueToCheck) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool noRowDuplicates(int arrPosition, int valueToCheck) {
    int rowPosition = arrPosition % inputNum; // 0 to num - 1
    if (rowPosition > 0) {
        for (int p = 1; p < rowPosition; p++) {
            if (grid[arrPosition - p] == valueToCheck) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void fill(int arrayPosition) {
    if (arrayPosition < gridSize) {
        int randomPosition = rand() % allOptionsSize;
        grid[arrayPosition] = allOptions[randomPosition];
        if (noColumnDuplicates(arrayPosition, grid[arrayPosition])) {
            if (noRowDuplicates(arrayPosition, grid[arrayPosition])) {
                if (arrayPosition % inputNum == 0) {
                    cout << endl;
                }
                cout << grid[arrayPosition] << " ";
                fill(arrayPosition + 1);
            } else {
                fill (arrayPosition);
            }
        } else {
            fill(arrayPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it throw a seg fault on any particular line?

Comment: It's saying line 67, which is just the line that calls noRowDuplicates. I noticed that when this error occurs, it stops printing the rest of the grid but always stops after printing a whole row (it never will throw the error and print only part of a row of the grid)

Comment: You are probably stepping out of bounds of one of your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`noRowDuplicates` never tests the first element of a row, which makes sense when you are trying to fill the first element of a row, but not any other time.

Comment: Thanks! The algorithm now correctly doesn't display duplicates. However the occasional segmentation error is still there

Comment: ***However the occasional segmentation error is still there*** Time to fire up your favorite debugger and let it tell you which line in your code is causing the crash.